# Accessing Windows Forms 2.0 combobox or AXComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, combobox

I have created a mutli-column combobox in VB.net 2008 using windows forms 2.0. I am having trouble accessing data once selected to use in the remainder of the form. There does not seem to be a selected event to use in conjunction with the winform 2.0 combobox.

Does anyone have any experience using winforms 2.0? Also I guess a better question would be: is there a site with a break down of windows forms 2.0? As so far nothing seems to be that detailed including MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We bought infragistics controls and that resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SelectIndexChanged Event for the ComboBox Class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx

SelectIndexChanged :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

SelectedValueChanged:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx

All Winform controls are documented pretty well on the msdn website.

Answer (score 0):

The controls I am speaking of are in: axmicrosoft.vbe.interop.forms.axcombobox.
Which does not have much in the way of documentation. It does lend itself to creating multi-column comboboxes however.

I am not excited about the prospect of creating multi-column comboboxes, and I have explained and demonstrated to the customer that this is not the best implementation, but the customer still wants a multi-column combobox.

I am also open to the prospect of third party tools (free, and not free).

If anyone has any experience with this issue please forward any information they have.